How to get authenticated user id in laravel 9
I need the user id of the logged in user in order to fetch the data associated with that specific id.
I need to test the api in postman so also i need to know how to get the bearer token in order to test my api. I'm using laravel 9 with sanctum
I've tried getting the auth id with
$id = Auth::id()
But then i need the bearer token inorder to login.

You can get the authenticated user's ID using:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$userId = Auth::id();

